# CSS Transform property not working in Safari correctly

Tags: css, safari

I have a website that I'm re-designing and one of the problems I'm having is that when i use

```
#cssmenu ul {
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

It seems to act up only in Safari. It's making the perspective go slanted. Does anybody know why it would do this? The CSS works fine in Chrome, IE and Firefox no problem.

To view the website here is the link. www.offsetprinting.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform-style and perspective must be used in conjunction with the transform property. Try something like this (add your transform values):

```
#cssmenu ul {
  -webkit-transform: "some value here";
  transform: "some value here";
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: Just tried to see if this fixed the problem. Sadly it's still slanted oddly in Safari only. The employee in my office mostly use Macs so it's frustrating that it works on everything except Safari.